# May I ask for a simple example of pyspark calling .so library on each work node?

Tags: pyspark, shared-libraries

Hi I suppose to be a C programmer and comfort on using C to run different jobs and researches.

However, my job (in an internet IT company) puts on a super preference on python.

I personally would not mind to learn and gradually find my way, but pressures were put and I need to realize the method of calling c function in quick.

Thus may I ask for just a simple example to prove to my colleagues that spark can parallel call c library using pyspark??? So that I would have a skeleton of what I should do and will dive into it.

Thanks very much for providing any help. And sorry for the question.

Comment: Would it be possible to upload the .so library when submitting. And using rdd.mappartitions() method to call a predefined python function. Within which it will import ctypes package and calling the c library??

Comment: I haven't personally tried it but this could help : https://medium.com/@thomaspt748/integrate-c-c-libraries-dll-so-into-apache-spark-scala-in-hadoop-cluster-56cdb26e15ea

Comment: Here's another link : https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/integrating-existing-c-libraries-into-pyspark-with-esther-kundin

Comment: The same using pipe operator : http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/pipe-in-spark/  . Facebook uses it for its large data processing : https://engineering.fb.com/2017/02/07/core-data/using-apache-spark-for-large-scale-language-model-training/